# Somar todos os valores de uma coluna e agrupar a cada 2 minutos

Tags: sql, postgresql

Queria somar todos os valores a cada 2 minutos e agrupar esses mesmos valores

```
valor     tempo
0.3    2019-05-22 01:11:45---> first value 0,3
0.3    2019-05-22 01:12:16-----|
0.3    2019-05-22 01:13:26-----|second value 0,6
0.2    2019-05-22 01:13:56---|
0.4    2019-05-22 01:14:06---|
0.6    2019-05-22 01:15:43 --|third value 1,2
```

Mas o que queria era isto:

```
valor     tempo
0.3    2019-05-22 01:11:45
0.6    2019-05-22 01:13:45
1.2    2019-05-22 01:15:45
```

---

Meu codigo em postgresql, falta somar e fazer o group by tempo, porem nao estou a conseguir fazer isso

```
SET search_path TO estufa;

SELECT (medi_sensor.valor/3600) *220 , tempo
FROM medi_sensor
    JOIN sensor ON medi_sensor.sensor_nome = sensor.nome
    JOIN mote ON num_mot=mot_id 
    JOIN divisao ON divisao_id=id_div
WHERE medi_sensor.sensor_nome LIKE 'corrente%' AND divisao.nome='MORANGOS' AND tempo>'2019-05-22' AND tempo<'2019-05-24'
ORDER BY tempo ASC
```

Comment: Este "a cada dois minutos" e : dois minutos iniciando de cada tempo inicial ou contar intervalos de dois minutos  00:00:00 00:02:00 00:04:00 00:06:00 ?

Comment: Não sei se entendi corretamente mas você pode utilizar a Set Returning Function:
generate_series(menor tempo de sua tabela, maior tempo de sua tabela, '00:02:00'::interval)
e utilizar o resultado em uma junção com sua tabela com o correspondente GROUP BY.

Comment: @Motta 2 minutos a partir do tempo inicial, se tempo inicial = 17:00 então a tabela fica 17:00, 17:02, 17:04, 17:06....etc

Comment: @anonimo Sim, sei que há essa função, porém nem tenho 1 mes desde que estou a aprender sql e por isso não consigo fazer esse tipo de lógica ainda.

Comment: Tente combimar isto https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158907/how-do-i-generate-a-time-series-in-postgresql com sua sql uma serie para cada "valor" intervalk minimo e maximo a sql faria um between para montar o intervalo https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160654/postgres-sum-time-of-this-interval-and-group-by-30-and-30-minutes